# Incrementally crawl a website with Scrapy

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler

I am new to crawling and would like to know whether it's possible to use Scrapy to crawl a site, like CNBC.com, incrementally? For example, if today I crawled all pages from a site, then from tomorrow I only want to collect pages that are newly posted to this site, to avoid crawling all the old pages.

Thank you for any info. or input on this.

Comment: Broadly no, you have to scrape all pages to see what has changed. However you might get away, in some sites, with retrieving the first X bytes of each document (assuming the server supports `Range` queries) to get an update timestamp from the `meta` tags.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can and it's actually quite easy. Every news website has a few very important index pages like the homepage and the categories (eg politics, entertainment etc.) There is no article that doesn't go through these pages for at least a few minutes. Scan those pages every minute or so and save just the links. Then do a diff with what you already have in your databases and a few times a day issue a crawl to scrape all the missing links. Very standard practice.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the scrapy plugin [scrapy-deltafetch](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-deltafetch) , which would make your life easier.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no.

Longer answer: What you could do is write the article id or the article url to a file and during the scraping, you would match the id or url with the records in the file.

Remember to load your file only once and assign it to a variable. Don't load it during your iteration when scraping.

Comment: Is this the common practice to do incremental crawling? I though this is a common task for most, if not all, web crawlers. In such a case, every time you have to repeat visiting all pages that have been visited before. Does Google also do this way? It sounds like a terrible job given the fact that the whole web is so huge.

Comment: Google usually gets a sitemap from the owner of the website. What most crawlers do, is basically go through all the links it finds on a site. Doesn't matter if it was already crawled. If the site is done correctly, an article page would have micro data snippets (vcard or something it was called) with author, published timestamp, ratings etc. Which helps the google bot a lot

Comment: De-duplication happens as post-processing step on those large companies... Not at the crawler level. This is how they attribute and penalise duplicate content. They also have refresh frequencies for each URL/domain depending on how quickly content changes on sites. They also don't care about sitemaps :-) but they respect robots.txt. Annotations are nice and I guess they might have been promoted for a while in an effort to move the industry forward to better quality markup and pave the way to more semantic content but they aren't essential neither for search nor for identifying unique content.